# What is the preferable way for passing Bean dependencies in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, javabeans

When reading through the documentation of the Spring framework, I stumbled upon two different styles of passing Bean dependencies in factory methods. The first one is like this (directly using the factory method of the dependency):

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    }

}
```

The second one looks like this (injecting the dependency as a parameter in the factory method):

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

}
```

I would like to know what are the PROs and CONs of the two solutions and which one is preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal use cases there shouldn't be such a big difference between the two approaches. But if your want to split your configuration into multiple classes the first solution cannot simply be used. Assumed you want to put your two @Bean methods into separate classes and import the first one into the second one through @Import, there is no chance for the compiler to know the connectionFactory() method of the first class in the RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory()) constructor of the second class. So you will run into a compiler error. To solve this problem you can use the second approach as recommended by the spring documentation: [Injecting dependencies on imported @Bean definitions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-injecting-imported-beans)

> Injecting dependencies on imported @Bean definitions
>
> The example above works, but is simplistic. In most practical
>   scenarios, beans will have dependencies on one another across
>   configuration classes. When using XML, this is not an issue, per se,
>   because there is no compiler involved, and one can simply declare
>   ref="someBean" and trust that Spring will work it out during container
>   initialization. Of course, when using @Configuration classes, the Java
>   compiler places constraints on the configuration model, in that
>   references to other beans must be valid Java syntax.
>
> Fortunately, solving this problem is simple. As we already discussed,
>   @Bean method can have an arbitrary number of parameters describing the
>   bean dependencies. Let’s consider a more real-world scenario with
>   several @Configuration classes, each depending on beans declared in
>   the others:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        return new TransferServiceImpl(accountRepository);
    }

}

@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig {

    @Bean
    public AccountRepository accountRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcAccountRepository(dataSource);
    }

}

@Configuration
@Import({ServiceConfig.class, RepositoryConfig.class})
public class SystemTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // return new DataSource
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new     AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SystemTestConfig.class);
    // everything wires up across configuration classes...
    TransferService transferService = ctx.getBean(TransferService.class);
    transferService.transfer(100.00, "A123", "C456");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you'll get consensus on "preferrable" on this.

A PRO for the second style is that it'll work, as-is, regardless of where the dependent bean is defined.

For example, if the two beans in question were defined in two separate @Configuration classes, style one would become this:

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration1 {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

}

@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration2 {

    @Autowired
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;    

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        return new RabbitTemplate(this.connectionFactory);
    }

}
```

While the second style would remain unchanged:

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration1 {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

}

@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration1 {

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

}
```

A second PRO is that it makes it easier to see when a bean has too many dependencies, which means it might be doing too much, which means it might be time for a refactor.

I was actually unaware of the second style up until a few weeks ago but it's what I've been using since.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The second (if you consider testing at the point of writing your code, too). Always try to avoid hard-wiring and create instances by means of dependency-injection so that it will be much easier to test your code (e.g. Mocking https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) and stay configurable.

Comment: What do you mean by hard-wiring? Both snippets perform constructor injection into `RabbitTemplate`.

Comment: In your first example, `RabbitTemplate` uses the direct result of the `connectionFactory()` method.

Comment: I'm not OP.  The result of calling `connectionFactory` is cached. All invocations will return the same value.

Comment: guess the relevant section in the spring test documentation is this here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans - if I got it right, the first snippet above doesn't allow Spring to inject the mocked dependency, where the second method allows to do so - am I right?

Comment: Please edit your answer to clarify that and the part about _as many instances_.

Comment: Edited. Better now?

Comment: Hm - seems like your point is not valid - see https://gist.github.com/michaellihs/700cb3bfd961e1566682040fce6d4e98 mocking works with both styles, so there is no argument in that...

Comment: When considering this example - yes. But in general things tend to be a bit more complex and then it might make sense to keep things separate.